# Why doesn't Scheme support first class environments?

Tags: scheme, racket

I've been reading through SICP (Structure and Interpration of Computer Programs) and was really excited to discover this wonderful special form: "make-environment", which they demonstrate to use in combination with eval as a way of writing modular code (excerpt from section 4.3 on "packages"):

```
(define scientific-library
  (make-environment
   ...
   (define (square-root x)
    ...)))
```

They then demonstrate how it works with

```
((eval 'square-root scientific-library) 4)
```

In their example, they then go on to demonstrate *exactly* the usage that I would want - an elegant, minimalist way of doing the "OO" style in scheme... They "cons" together a "type", which is actually what was returned by the "make-environment" special form (i.e. the vtable), and an arg ("the state")...

I was so excited because this is *exactly* what I've been looking for as a way to do polymorphic dispatch "by symbol" in Scheme without having to write lots of explicit code or macros.

i.e. I want to create an "object" that has, say, *two* functions, that I call in different contexts... but I don't want to refer to them by "car" and "cdr", I want to both *declare* and *evaluate* them by their symbolic names.

Anyway, when I read this I couldn't wait to get home and try it.

Imagine my disappointment then when I experienced the following in both PLT Scheme and Chez Scheme:

```
> (make-environment (define x 3))
Error: invalid context for definition (define x 3).
> (make-environment)
Error: variable make-environment is not bound.
```

What happened to "make-environment" as referenced in SICP? It all seemed so elegant, and exactly what I want, yet it doesn't seem to be supported in any modern Scheme interpreters?

What's the rationale? Is it simply that "make-environment" has a different name?

**More information found later**

I took at look at the online version:

https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-28.html#%_sec_4.3

I was reading was the first edition of SICP. The second edition appears to have replaced the discussion on packages with a section on non-deterministic programming and the "amp" operator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After more digging around I discovered this [informative thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.scheme/browse_frm/thread/78ee853ca52c84fd/6a452d426eab0e53?lnk=gst&q=make-environment#6a452d426eab0e53) on newsnet:

"The R5RS EVAL and environment specifiers are a compromise between
those who profoundly dislike first-class environments and want a
restricted EVAL, and those who can not accept/understand EVAL without
a second argument that is an environment."

Also, found this "work-around":

```
(define-syntax make-environment 
  (syntax-rules () 
    ((_ definition ...) 
     (let ((environment (scheme-report-environment 5))) 
       (eval '(begin definition 
                     ...) 
             environment) 
       environment)))) 


(define arctic 
  (make-environment 
    (define animal 'polarbaer)))
```

(taken from [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.scheme/browse_frm/thread/b083c43f0f1545e1/37ebb30db69cd507?lnk=gst&q=make-environment#37ebb30db69cd507))

However, I ended up adopting a "message passing" style kinda of like the first guy suggested - I return an alist of functions, and have a generic "send" method for invoking a particular function by name... i.e something like this

```
(define multiply
  (list
    (cons 'differentiate (...))
    (cons 'evaluate (lambda (args) (apply * args)))))

(define lookup
  (lambda (name dict)
    (cdr (assoc name dict))))

; Lookup the method on the object and invoke it
(define send
  (lambda (method arg args)
    ((lookup method arg) args)))

((send 'evaluate multiply) args)
```

I've been reading further and am aware that there's all of CLOS if I really wanted to adopt a fully OO style - but I think even above is somewhat overkill.

Comment: The make-environment macro is great, but I still miss one thing: I'd like to have a way to *verify* if a symbol is bound in an environment, using only standard R5RS, and as far as I know, this isn't possible without ugly hacks like storing a table of defined names, etc)

Comment: Hm, I just noticed that the make-environment trick may or may not work on a Scheme implementation: scheme-report-environment *may* be immutable, and also, the LET inside the macro may not copy the environment. There doesn't seem to be a portable way to create an environment in Scheme (at least not in R5RS).

Answer (score 5):

They wrote it like that because MIT Scheme does, in fact, have first-class environments, and presumably that's what the writers were planning to teach their class with (since the book was written at MIT).

Check out http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/scheme/

However, I've noticed that MIT Scheme, while still somewhat actively developed, lacks many of the features that a really modern Scheme would have, like a foreign function interface or GUI support. You probably wouldn't want to use it for a serious software development project, at least not by itself.

Answer (score 4):

Scheme has no first-class environments because of performance reasons. When Scheme was created, it wasn't the fastest language around due to nifty stuff like first-class functions, continuations, etc. Adding first-class environments would have crippled the performance even further. So it was a trade-off made in the early Scheme days.

Comment: Do you have any references on this please?

Answer (score 1):

Would a classical dispatcher function work? I think this is similar to what you're looking for.

```
(define (scientific-library f)
  (define (scientific-square-root x) (some-scientific-square-root x))
  (cond ((eq? f 'square-root) scientific-square-root)
        (else (error "no such function" f))))
(define (fast-library f)
  (define (fast-square-root x) (some-fast-square-root x))
  (cond ((eq? f 'square-root) fast-square-root)
        (else (error "no such function" f))))

((scientific-library 'square-root) 23)
((fast-library 'square-root) 23)
```

You could even combine the example scientific and fast libraries into one big dispatch method:

```
(define (library l f)
  (define (scientific-library f)
    ...)
  (define (fast-library f)
    ...)
  (cond ((eq? l 'scientific) (scientific-library f))
        ((eq? l 'fast) (fast-library f))
        (else (error "no such library" l))))
(library 'fast 'square-root)
```

Comment: Yes but writing the above is so tedious and verbose!